# Regex to match Strings which contain non Chinese characters between two Chinese Characters

Tags: regex

I'm trying to figure out how to write a regex to match this pattern

测试1003##$%#测试

Chinese Characters + non Chinese Characters + Chinese Characters, non Chinese Characters can be anything, and Chinese Characters are always the same(测试).

I know we can use `^((?!(\p{Han}).)*$` to match non Chinese Characters.. but not sure how should I make sure the head and tail are always the same Chinese Characters（测试 in this case).

Answer (score 0):

If there should be at least a single character other than `\p{Han}` you can match `\P{Han}`.

Capture the `\p{Han}` chars in capture group 1, and add a backreference at the end to group 1.

```
^(\p{Han}+)\P{Han}.*\1$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(\p{Han}+)` Capture group 1, match 1+ chars in the han script
- `\P{Han}` Match at least a char other than `\p{Han}`
- `.*` Match the rest of the string
- `\1$` Match a backreference to group 1 at the end of the string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IJW42K/1)

To also match only `测试` you can use:

```
^(\p{Han}+)(?:\P{Han}.*\1)?$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nyUMPn/1)

Comment: what if I need the Chinese Character to be 测试 only. `(?<=测试)^(\p{Han}+)(?=测试)` tried this, but not working...

Comment: @Rocket Like this https://regex101.com/r/9YrFZk/1

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
^(\p{Han}+)\P{Han}*\g{1}$
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/APfZoc/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```php
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \p{Han}+                     Chinese characters 
                             (1 or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \P{Han}                  non-word Chinese characters (0 or more times 
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \g{1}                    matches the same text as most recently matched
                           by the 1st capturing group
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

If prefix = suffix = `测试`, then use

```php
^测试\P{Han}*测试$
```

Or, if the suffix and prefix can include more Chinese characters:

```php
^测试\p{Han}*\P{Han}*\p{Han}*测试$
```